# Remove specific JS code with a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried searching around but couldn't find a solution to this.

I am running two main JS functions on a site I am building. One which is lazy load, and one which is a smooth scroll, the latter for an anchor link to the bottom of the page.

However, with them both being present, they conflict each other as you can't anchor smooth scroll to the bottom of the page with lazyload... it just isn't happening.

Is there a way to disable lazyload if the user clicks on the anchor link? Thus making it work, and if they don't, then the lazyload works just fine?

Lazy Load:

```
<script>
     $("img").lazyload({
         threshold : 10000,
         placeholder : "images/white.gif",       
         effect      : "fadeIn"
     });
        </script>
```

Smooth scroll (although unfortunately this works for ALL anchor links... grrr):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          function filterPath(string) {
          return string
            .replace(/^\//,'')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
            .replace(/\/$/,'');
          }
          var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
          var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

          $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
            var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
            if (  locationPath == thisPath
            && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
            && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
              var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
              if (target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1400, function() {
                    location.hash = target;
                  });
                });
              }
            }
          });

          // use the first element that is "scrollable"
          function scrollableElement(els) {
            for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
              var el = arguments[i],
                  $scrollElement = $(el);
              if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
                return el;
              } else {
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                if (isScrollable) {
                  return el;
                }
              }
            }
            return [];
          }

        });
          </script>
```

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: When a script is executed, function definitions are added to the global window object , so you can't , could u show us error ?

Comment: Even if you could make these two plugins work together, lazyloading is anathema to page-scrolling. What does it mean to scroll to a specific place in on a page of unknown length? 

Unless your page is very specifically constructed so as not to change size based on the presence of images, then having it scroll  to a "specific" unknown offset (when new content will constantly be inserted during the trip down) will be problematic.

Comment: posssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376235/is-it-possible-to-disable-lazyload-so-all-images-gets-loaded

Comment: Hmm, there must be a way to disable a certain JS script with a click of a link? That's all I need. The two don't work hand in hand, yes, but if lazyload could be disabled if someone clicks a specific link or button, that would surely solve it?

Comment: Any answers? There must be a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the contents of the script with the contents surrounded by comments /* */ on click and then re-enable by removing these comments /* */. If the script never needs to be used again on the same page you could place the script inside a container element with an id and use jquery to remove that element from the page on click event. Another option that may work would be to alter the javascript to check a 'flag' that is toggled upon clicking the anchor link, the 'flag' can just be a javascript variable in the page that prevents the scripts you don't want to run from running.

Comment: Could I do the same for adding comments? As in essence, I'd want the onClick to stop the script, not start the script. Thanks so much for your help so far.